# How to retrieve rows NOT common in two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables:

**tata_data1:**

```
Password | Region | Company | System
-------------------------------------
a02040   | Del    | xx      | abc
a01917   | Mum    | xxx     | pqr
a01916   | Mum    | x       | zzz
a01906   | Nag    | x       | pny
```

and **tata_passwords:**

```
Password | Region | Company
----------------------------
a02049   | Nag    | xxxx
a01917   | Mum    | xxx
a01000   | Del    | xx
a01906   | Nag    | x
```

I want to fetch only those rows from tata_passwords, which are not there in tata_data1.  Consider **Password** as the primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM tata_passwords WHERE (Password, Region, Company) NOT IN ( SELECT Password, Region, Company FROM tata_data1 )
```

**EDIT:**

Now when Password is primary key, one could reduce the query to:

```
SELECT * FROM tata_passwords WHERE Password NOT IN ( SELECT Password FROM tata_data1 )
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a LEFT OUTER JOIN:-

```
SELECT  tata_passwords.*
FROM  tata_passwords
LEFT OUTER JOIN tata_data1
ON tata_passwords.Password = tata_data1.Password
WHERE tata_data1.Password IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tata_passwords 
where tata_passwords.password NOT IN (select password from tata_data1)
```

Or you can use **Mr.Kickstart** said `LEFT OUTER JOIN`

```
SELECT tata_passwords.*
FROM tata_passwords LEFT OUTER JOIN tata_data1 ON tata_passwords.password=tata_data1.password 
where tata_data1.password IS NULL
```